# Ajax request not passed to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, jstl

I send an AJAX request to my **controller**. This development done in JSP and Spring environment. **SimpleFormController** is overridden by the **controller** I'm using.

Using JavaScript I create the object and send the request. this request is not getting passed to controller.

JavaScript code which send the request.

```
function getStates(){
    var httpRequest;
    var country = document.getElementById('countryName');
    alert(country);
    var url = '/developer/register.htm';

    url = url + (url.match(new RegExp('\\?')) ? '&isAjax=true' : '?isAjax=true');

     if (window.ActiveXObject)
     {
         httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
     else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {
         httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     }

     httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
     httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {processRequest(); };
     httpRequest.send(null);
}

function processRequest() {
    if(httpRequest.readyState == 4){
        alert("inside ready state");
        var response = http.responseText;
        document.getElementById('states').innerHTML = response;
    }
}
```

Variable `url` is given in the way how I have mentioned in **dispatcher servlet**.

The browser shows an **error** in **processRequest()** function telling that httpRequest is not defined. but, I don't get this error in the previous lines. I use this object in **getStates()** function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because variable `httpRequest` should be defined outside `getStates()` function. Otherwise `processRequest()` cannot see it.

Comment: Error is not repeated when I changed the scope of the variable. Thanks for the support. But, the request is not redirected to the controller. Please advice on this if anyone have idea on this.

Comment: I suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or other js libraries to get rid of these ajax problems. Ajax can be very complex, and these libraries provide convenient ways to handle it.

Comment: can you please name any library or can you please put a reference link if you know. It will be really appreciable. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: [This is a nice list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks#JavaScript). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I got my task done. Appreciate your response for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Either declare `httpRequest` outside `getStates()` (as a global variable) or pass it to `processRequest()`:

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { processRequest(httpRequest); };

function processRequest(httpRequest) {
```

Comment: Error is not repeated when I changed the scope of the variable. Thanks for the support. But, the request is not redirected to the controller. Please advice on this if anyone have idea on this.